# Is it possible to make a button with multiple borders and drop shadow?

Tags: css, button, styles

This is the button im looking to make with CSS

[image: button]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e6df392f64d28b0a7e88cb80c946bc30.png))</sub>

ignore the grey background

I've tried cropping the center and adding border top, left, right but still looks weird.
Any ideas on how to create it in only CSS?

It has a white drop shadow, live preview: http://justxp.plutohost.net/themetheory/portfolio.html

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What browser(s) are you targeting? Is http://thoughtbot.github.com/bourbon/#buttons what you want?

Comment: Best to have a go at it, post up your css/html and then the community can try and help out.

Comment: Im looking for all browsers and IE9+ and as I said i have no idea on how to create them, I was asking of multiple borders is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with smth like this. Experiment with colors and fonts to get what you need

```
a {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
  background:#5a81ff;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid #656565;
  border-top-color:#cacaca;
  line-height:40px;    

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(176, 176, 176, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 0px rgba(176, 176, 176, 1);
  box-shadow:         0px 2px 0px rgba(176, 176, 176, 1);
}​
```

p.s. Working expm - http://jsfiddle.net/6zhDt/

p.p.s. If you want to know more - http://vimeo.com/31719130 Brilliant Lea Verou talks about multiple borders with shadows starting from about tenth minute.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your desired result **Multiple Borders** through `before: after:` **pseudo classes** see the demo:-

[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/RBoeD7Sm)

**HTML**

```
<div id="borders"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#borders {
   position: relative;
   border: 5px solid #f00;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#borders:before {
   content: " ";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   border: 5px solid #ffea00;
}
#borders:after {
   content: " ";
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   left: 5px;
   right: 5px;
   bottom: 5px;
   border: 5px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's blog post at CSSTricks.com - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Kjuly You mean links like the one to the OP's website?  Fiddles aren't invincible either.  Maybe you'd like to suggest disallowing links all together?  The OP doesn't even know if multiple borders are possible, and clearly hadn't done any research on the subject (googling "css multiple borders" brings up the CSSTricks link at #1).

Comment: Hi @cimmanon, this comment is auto generated by system when I've reviewed this answer as a Low Quality Post (someone or system might flag this answer). And that's what SO formulated. You can take a look at [THIS QA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Hope this'll resolve your doubt. Thanks. :)